# How to run ansible 'lineinfile' with a condition

Tags: ansible

I am using the **lineinfile** module, but it does not support the **when** clause.
What would be an easy way to make it run only on Ubuntu (==Debian family) but not on CentOS? 
I think I could use the **validate** clause but is there another way? If not, I would appreciate a working example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure _all_ modules support `when`. Can you add an example? Maybe you just put the `when` at the module options level instead the task level?

Comment: is there a reason you can't use `template`? Can you give an example of the code you have tried to use?

Answer (score 2):

The `lineinfile` task most certainly does support the `when` clause, along with all the other standard task modifiers.  Here's a simple test case:

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - local_action: lineinfile
                    dest=/tmp/test.txt
                    line="this is a test"
                    state=present
      when: foo is defined
```

When run without defining the variable `foo`:

```
TASK: [lineinfile dest=/tmp/test.txt line="this is a test" state=present] *****
skipping: [localhost]
```

When run *with* `foo` defined:

```
TASK: [lineinfile dest=/tmp/test.txt line="this is a test" state=present] *****
changed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1]
```

So simply adding the following to your task should do what you want:

```
when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
```

Comment: According to my Ansible (version `2.4.3.0`) the `lineinfile` module doe not seem to be supporting the keyword `when`. See the attached error: `Unsupported parameters for (lineinfile) module: when Supported parameters include: attributes,backrefs,backup,content,create,delimiter,directory_mode,follow,force,group,insertafter,insertbefore,line,mode,owner,path,regexp,remote_src,selevel,serole,setype,seuser,src,state,unsafe_writes,validate` EDIT: Sorry, when needs to be indented to the same level as the task, not its paramters. Welcome to the Yaml hell.